# Curiously Recurring Template Pattern times two

Tags: c++, scientific-computing, crtp

I have general design question. I am trying to implement something like this:

```
                  ------------
                  |Base Class|
                  ------------
                       |
               ------------------
               |                |
          -----------      -----------
          |SubClass1|      |SubClass2|
          -----------      -----------
               |                |
         --------------   --------------
         |SubSubClass1|   |SubSubClass2|
         --------------   --------------
```

where the base class provides virtual functions, the subclasses the implementation, and the subsubclasses provide constants to the implementations.

I thought about using the "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern" twice like this:

```
// header baseclass.h
template <typename subclass>
class baseclass {
private:

public:

  virtual double GetQuantity1(double given1, double given2) = 0;

  virtual double GetQuantity2(double given1) = 0; 

}

// header subclass1.h
template <typename n>
class subclass1:public baseclass<subclass>{
private:

  private1(double, double);

public:

  double GetQuantity1(double given1, double given2);

  double GetQuantity2(double given1); 

}

// header subsubclass1.h
class subsubclass1:public subclass1<subsubclass1>{
private:

public:

  double constant1;

  double constant2;
}
```

I would then call Subsubclass::GetQuantity1() when using the code.

Is something like thing kosher or are there better ways to do something like this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to do so, and I don't see any general disadvantage of doing this. I just don't get where you're actually using the CRTP and why simple virtual inheritance won't work for your use case (CRTP is usually used as static polymorphism).

Also don't get what you mean with

```
private1(double, double);
```

in your `subclass1` did you mean a constructor? As it stands it won't compile when instantiated (functions aren't allowed without return value besides constructors or destructors).

Another critics would be: If you mean constants, you should declare `const` or `static const` members in your subsubclasses.

<strike>Since you don't clearly specify your particular use case it's hard to say what would really be the best design for it.</strike> I can just provide an alternative grasped from trying to follow your thoughts:

```
// header baseclass.h
template <typename subclass>
class baseclass {
public:

    inline double GetQuantity1(double given1, double given2) {
        // may be add a static check for GetQuantity1_Impl with a traits 
        // check on subclass.
        return static_cast<subclass*>(this)->GetQuantity1_Impl(given1,given2);
    }

    inline double GetQuantity2(double given1) {
        return static_cast<subclass*>(this)->GetQuantity2_Impl(given1);
    }

    // You also can provide default implementations, otherwise the interface
    // method will be required from subclass to compile correctly
    inline double GetQuantity1_Impl(double given1, double given2) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

---

```
// header subclass1.h
template<double const1, double const2>
class subclass1:public baseclass<subclass1>{
public:
    subclass1() {}

    double GetQuantity1_Impl(double given1, double given2) {
        return 0.0; // Apply formula using the constants instead of 0.0
    }
    double GetQuantity2_Impl(double given1) {
        return 0.0; // Apply formula using the constants instead of 0.0
    }
};
```

---

```
// Client implementation file
// No need for subsubclass1 just instantiate for usage

subclass1<0.3, 3.1415> myAlgo;
// A client calls the public interface of the (implicit) base class
double result1 = myAlgo.GetQuantity1(23.2,42);
double result2 = myAlgo.GetQuantity2(2.71828);
```

Eliminate the pure virtual method definitions in the base class, and replace them with a static interface ('traits') check on the `subclass` template parameter.

Comment: @madtowneast If you wanted to use the CRTP because of performance considerations regarding the function calls you should eliminate the pure virtual methods (and virtual implementations), otherwise I don't see, why it's needed over simple virtual inheritance.

Comment: In my use case I need to get 5 quantities (two energy, total and differential cross-section, and outgoing angle) from three physical process types that are then split into 8 physical processes. So the base class defines the quantities, the subclasses implements the formulas, i.e functions, and the subsubclasses provide the constants that separate the physical processes.

Comment: i am concerned about speed because I am going to call any of the functions multiple billion times and it adds up after a while

Comment: @madtowneast Yup, guessed such reasoning. I'll edit my alternative example in this direction.

Comment: doesnt putting the implementation in the header slow down the code?

Comment: @madtowneast No. Why should this slow down the code? Template instantiated code needs to be seen completely through headers anyway.